# How to move from gitalb source base to gitlab omnibus?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I am trying to move `gitlab-ce 8.5` source base to `gitlab-ce 8.15 omnibus`. We were using `MySQL in source base but now we have to use the`psql with gitlab-ce omnibus`. When I was trying to take a backup so it was failing due to some empty repo.

**Question:** Is it any alternative way to move source base to omnibus with full backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved gitlab from source base to the omnibus. You can use below link to convert db dump from MySQL to psql.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/mysql_to_postgresql.md

I have created a zip file of repos manually & copied to the gitlab omnibus server & restore it on /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repository/.

After these steps, copy the below script on /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/xyz.sh & executed for updating the hooks.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in repositories/* ; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    for o in $i/* ; do
     if [ -d "$i" ]; then
       rm "$o/hooks"
       # change the paths if required
       ln -s  "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks" /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/"$o"/hooks 
       echo "HOOKS CHANGED ($i/$o)"
     fi
    done
  fi
done
```

**Note: Repos permission should be git:git**

Some useful commands during the migration:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl start postgres **to start the Postgres service only**

sudo gitlab-psql **to use the gitlab bundle postgres.**
```

Feel free to comment if you face 5xx errors code on gitlab page.